# Почему бот не отвечает пользователям параллельно, а в порядке очереди?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Пытаюсь создать Telegram-бота с нейросетями от OpenAI, в папке modules находятся асинхронные функции, которыми обладает бот. Единственным не рабочим моментом является то, что бот отвечает пользователям в порядке очереди, а не параллельно. Как возможно это исправить?

```py
import os
import openai
import logging
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from modules.handlers import start, info, support
from modules.roles import role_handler
from modules.images import paint
from modules.chatgpt import reset, chat_gpt
from modules.admin import advertise_to_users
from modules.dispatcher import dp
from aiogram.utils import executor

logging.basicConfig(filename='errors/errors.log', level=logging.ERROR, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(lineno)d %(message)s')

load_dotenv()

openai.api_key = os.environ.get('OpenAI')

dp.register_message_handler(start, commands=['start', 'help'])
dp.register_message_handler(info, commands=['info'])
dp.register_message_handler(support, commands=['support'])

dp.register_message_handler(role_handler, commands=['role'])

dp.register_message_handler(paint, commands=['image'])
dp.register_message_handler(reset, commands=['reset'])
dp.register_message_handler(chat_gpt, lambda message: message.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        executor.start_polling(dp)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"An error occurred: {repr(e)}")
```

Comment: Вы используете асинхронные запросы к серверам с помощью `openai.Completion.acreate
Источник: https://openai.by/applications/openai-python-library`?

Comment: @gord1402

Нет, не использую, не знал об асинхронном запросе
```response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
    messages=user_messages[user_id]
)
reply = response.choices[0].message.content
```

Comment: `response = await openai.ChatCompletion.acreate(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", messages=user_messages[user_id] )` вот исправленная строка замените её и все должно работать нормально.

Comment: Сработало, большое спасибо